# Request with RabbitMQ NodeJs

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I'm pretty new here, so hope I can get some help with a basic doubt which I couldn't get around yet.

I'm using NodeJs and I have followed the Rabbiq GetStart and could understand the flow, however my doubt is with regards Http request.

What I need:

Manage http (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) requests to another server.

What I was expecting:

RabitMQ manage the request QUEUE, so if some request fail it would retry again. When its successful, it would call another API on my end to flag the request was successfull.

What is my question:

I couldn't find any example which I would setup this request, providing the sender URL, METHOD and PAYLOAD and also the callback URL, METHOD, HEADERS, and PAYLOAD.

Is that something related to RabbitMQ or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: and you want to throw all the http requests in rabbitmq ? I hope the use case is good. Why not proxy the request or use  load balancer to avoid heavy load if that's the case. Or handle the failed request in client side ...

Comment: The reason to do that is to send webhooks to third-part api's and also communicating between microservices. I don't know if there are better ways, but what I have been reading about microservices is that require uses of Message Queues to make sure that the message is delivery.

Comment: yes, message queues are used commonly used as a transport for communication between microservices. You should mention your case in your question. Anyways, you can create microservices to process messages in queue, and other microservices post messages don't think rabbitmq as problem solver instead use it only as transport, microservices can handle everything else, requeue a request, call webhooks etc, logs etc.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Phoenix